# select from table where two parameters satisfy in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am totally clueless how to get around to get the following kinda result from the same table in MySQL.

**Required Result:**

[image: required result]

The **raw data** as shown in below image.

[image: raw data in a table]

Mc_id and op_id can be different. For example, if mc_id is 4 and op_id is 10 then it has to loop through each vouid and extract done_on_date, again it has to loop through for the same mc_id 4 and op_id 10 and extract done_on_date where done_on_date is after first extracted done_on_date. Here second extracted done_on_date, we refer to, as next_done_on_date, just to distinguish it differently. Accordingly continue till end of the table. I hope I am clear enough now.

The idea is basically to see when was particular operation_id carried out for the said machine having mc_id. First time operation done is refered to as done_on_date and when the same operation carried out for the same machine next time, we refer to as next_done_on_date but actually inside the database table it is done_on_date.
Though let me know if anything yet to be clarified

Comment: How do you get the `next_done_on_date` value?

Comment: Sorry it’s the same as done on date but named it different just to distinguish.  How to find the next date for the same mc_id and op_id.

Comment: Also why is `vouid` not showing in the required result? You said you want to see all where `m/c id` = `op_id`. Is that right? And I don't know why you are showing `m/c_id` = 3 in the result either as there is no matching `op_id`

Comment: @Justin  vouid is not required bcoz we want a result of rows wherein each row will have data from two vouid. Let us say for example, you have 2 porsche cars defined as porsche_1 and porsche_2. Now, the porsche_1 is sent to mechanic for servicing 4 times in 1 year. Now let us assume the type of service mechanic performed is same called service_1. So, Service_1 first time done is 01/04/2017 for porsche_1. Service_1 second time done is 15/04/2017 for porsche_1. I would like these detail in a single row like, porsche_1, service_1, done_on_date (01/04/2017), done_on_date(15/04/2017).